# unable to use @ResponseBody to send json object in spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Upon trying to get my response in JSON using Spring 4.x, 
I get the 406 error :

**"The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ()."**

Here is my environment:

```
* Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE
* included jackson-all-1.9.0.jar
* Tomcat 6.x
* mvc:annotation-driven in Spring configuration XML file
```

**My Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllStudents", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<Student> getAllExpenses() {
    List<Student> students= studentDaoImp.getStudents();
    return students;
    //return new JsonJtableResponse().ok(students);
}
```

**My Spring Configuration file:**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <!-- telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- declaring base package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" /> -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>



    <!-- declare datasource bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test;instancename=mssqlserver1;" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="abc123" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="StudentDao" class="com.dao.StudentDaoImp">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: How did you test this resource?

Comment: on tomcat http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/getAllStudents

Comment: The http request you send contains an `"Accept: somthing/something` header that does not allow `application/json`. Content negotiation then fails because spring can't satisfy the request. https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Comment: Remove `produces="application/json"` in `@RequestMapping` annotation, and try again please.

Comment: i tried without it but its still not working

Comment: i tried including headers="Accept:application/json" too but even this one did not work

Comment: @zapl's comment contains solution imo, try to configure your content negotiation manager.

Comment: i tried conent negotiation manager also. even that is not working

Answer (score 0):

Add the following bean definition to your spring conf:

```
<!-- Total customization - see below for explanation. -->
  <bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
             class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
    <property name="parameterName" value="mediaType" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/> <!-- this should solve the problem -->
    <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />

    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
       </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Referring to http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc in zapl's comment above.

Comment: I think you should rebuild your project, ie `mvn clean install` if you are using maven.

Comment: i am not using maven. i am not using anything for handling dependency actually

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised the List it seems, try to do the below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllStudents", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Student> getAllExpenses() {
List<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();
students.add(studentDaoImp.getStudents());
return students;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring 4 [RestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) as follows:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class YourController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllStudents", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public List<Student> getAllExpenses() {
    List<Student> students= studentDaoImp.getStudents();
    return students;
 }
}
```

And add below dependencies in your `classpath`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Optionally you can remove below code from your **Spring Configuration file:**

```
    <!-- telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- declaring base package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
```